# Browser Repaint/Reflow performance: using CSS3 Gradients vs PNG Gradients

Tags: performance, reflow

I am working at an app that causes lots of browser reflows. Performance is a key issue here. From the performance point of view Is it better to use a CSS3 gradient or an image gradient for some DOM elements? Does a page that uses CSS text shadows and gradients will have a slower reflow as a page that uses images to achieve those visual effects?
Also, are there any reflow tests out there I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drawing, CSS gradients and shadows do task the CPU more than images. Performance used to be pretty bad, these days they are acceptable. If you have a ton of gradients/shadows, you should just implement them and do the tests in your real-world setting. If you just have a few, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how the browser renders it, but for the most part those things will render slower. In addition, you'll have a less pixel-perfect display in older browsers. However, this also serves to segment your audience, as generally those with updated browsers also have updated computers. So, it's a trade-off that can work in your favor to essentially serve a stripped down version of your site to those that wouldn't be able to handle it. It's not guaranteed, but I've found it usually balances out pretty well.

Overall, real-world testing is the way to go. Build it, see if it works, and fix performance issues once you find them. I wouldn't hesitate just because there's a chance it might not work. If it works just fine and you don't try it, you'll never know!